Evaluating estimator of expected value plus variation
I know that for a typical, the estimator can be evaluated based on the mean squared error (MSE) of the predictions. How can I evaluate an estimator that instead gives a value that is the prediction plus some variation?
For example, a software developer might estimate that a project will take 8 days of work. If they were instead asked "How long do you need such that there's an 80% chance the project is done in that time?", they might say 12 days instead. How can the second prediction be evaluated, once the actual value (how long the project actually took) is known?
A simple method of aggregate evaluation like "What proportion of the predictions were greater than the actual time?" doesn't work because a developer that guessed 100 days 80% of the time and 0 days 20% of the time would be a perfect fit.
Context: estimating project length is known to be a difficult problem in software development, and I was wondering if developers are more accurate when guessing a larger percentile instead of the expected value.

What you are looking for is probably loss/scoring functions for quantiles forecasts.
Let me rephrase your statement

"How long do you need such that there's an 80% chance the project is done in that time?"

I think that you want an answer to the question "What is the minimal duration such that there is at least an 80% chance that the project is done after this time?" The answer to this question is the quantile of the project duration distribution. Analogous to the MSE, which can be used to evaluate forecasts for the mean of this distribution, we can use quantile loss functions to evaluate quantile forecasts. The most popular one is the pinball loss, as discussed in this question for example.
For more details you can search for terms like 'scoring functions for quantiles' or 'quantiles regression' on this site or on the web. I also recommend Quantiles as optimal point forecasts by Tilmann Gneiting as a good introduction.
